# matlab progress bar not depanding on time

Tags: matlab, graph, progress-bar, progress

To explain my question i will give an example:

Let same i'm playing a game and i have 50Exp from 120Exp till i get my next level.

I would like to make a horizontal bar that shows 50/120 of the bar in green and the rest of it red. Just like progress bar but that depends on values and not on Matlab time calculation. I thought to use `Barh` graph but I don't need all the axis and stuff like this. I want it to look something like this.

[image]

If anyone knows i had like to know,

Thank you

Comment: [**`waitbar`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waitbar.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you are looking for is:

> draw a colored rectangle over another colored rectangle.

In MATLAB, a colored rectangle can be rendered with `axes`, `bar`, `surf`, `patch`, `image`, `rectangle`, or `annotation('rectangle')`, to name a few. The EXP bar can be drawn with a combination of the above mentioned graphical objects. I'll show you three ways to do it, but remember you at least have a dozen other choices of combinations.

1. Draw both red part('R') and green part('G') as `annotation('rectangle')`. **Pros:** Does not need to be drawn on an axes; **Cons:** You may have less control over its appearance compared to other methods.
2. Draw R as an `axes`, and G as `patch` (or `surf`, `image`). **Pros:** Greater appearance control. If you draw G as `surf` or `image`, you can even get 3D shading and pixel art effects. **Cons:** Axes is a little expensive to render. If you have a bunch of these bar around, it will cause significant lag.
3. Draw both R and G as stacked `barh` on an invisible axes. **Pros:** Can render multiple bars at a time. **Cons:** Must be drawn on an axes. It is not intuitive to control the absolute value of bar width.

Sample code: You can see how the 3 methods are animated.

```
% Background axes. This is just for texts.
main = axes('Position', [0, 0, 1, 1], 'Visible', 'off')

% Method 1: Use a red annotation rectangle as background, and overlay a
% green annotation rectangle on top.
text(0.1, 0.9, 'Annotation BKG + Annotation Front', 'Parent',main) 
barbkg_an = annotation('rectangle', [0.1, 0.8, 0.8, 0.05], 'EdgeColor','black', 'FaceColor', 'red');
barfront_an = annotation('rectangle', [0.1, 0.8, 0.3*0.8, 0.05], 'EdgeColor','None', 'FaceColor', 'green');

% Method 2: Use a red axis as background, and draw green patch on it.
text(0.1, 0.7, 'Axes BKG + Patch Front', 'Parent',main) 
barbkg_axes = axes('Position', [0.1, 0.6, 0.8, 0.05], 'Color', 'red', 'XColor', 'black', 'YColor','black','box','on','XTick',[],'YTick',[],'XLim',[0 1],'YLim',[0 1]);
bar_pc = patch([0 0.3 0.3 0], [0 0 1 1], [0 1 0]);

% Method 3: Draw "stacked" barh (so that both foreground and background are
% drawn with one barh call) on an invisible axes
text(0.1, 0.5, 'Axes BKG + Barh Front(X2)', 'Parent',main)  
barbkg_barh = axes;
bar_barh = barh([0.2 0.4], [0.3 0.3; 0.7 0.7]', 0.25, 'stacked','ShowBaseline','off')
colormap([0 1 0; 1 0 0])
set(barbkg_barh, 'Position', [0.1, 0, 0.8, 1], 'Visible','off','XLim',[0 1],'YLim',[0 1]);

% Animate them
for i = 0:0.01:1
    set(barfront_an, 'Position', [0.1, 0.8, i*0.8, 0.05]);
    set(bar_pc, 'XData', [0 i i 0]);
    set(bar_barh(1), 'YData',[i i])
    set(bar_barh(2), 'YData',1-[i i]);
    drawnow;
end
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way to have text in the middle of the patch? for i can see the % of green/red for example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`bar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html) or [`barh`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/barh.html) and just hide the axes elements you don't want to see.

For example:

```
function testcode()
% Initialize GUI
h.f = figure('MenuBar', 'none', 'NumberTitle', 'off', 'ToolBar', 'none');
h.ax = axes('Parent', h.f, 'Units', 'Normalized', 'Position', [0.1 0.45 0.8 0.1]);

myxp = 10;
totalxp = 120;

h.currentxpbox = uicontrol('Parent', h.f, 'Style', 'edit', ...
                           'Units', 'Normalized', 'Position', [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.1], ...
                           'String', myxp, 'Callback', @(o,e)updatebar(h.f));  % Ignore usual callback inputs
h.totalxpbox = uicontrol('Parent', h.f, 'Style', 'edit', ...
                         'Units', 'Normalized', 'Position', [0.6 0.2 0.3 0.1], ...
                         'String', totalxp, 'Callback', @(o,e)updatebar(h.f));  % Ignore usual callback inputs

% For whatever reason, MATLAB needs 2 bars in order to stack, so we can
% specify a dummy bar and render it outside of our axes limits
tmph = barh([1, 2], [myxp, totalxp-myxp; 1, 1], 'stacked');

h.expbar_L = tmph(1);
h.expbar_R = tmph(2);
barwidth = h.expbar_L.BarWidth;
h.ax.YLim = [1-barwidth/2 1+barwidth/2];

h.expbar_L.FaceColor = 'g';
h.expbar_R.FaceColor = 'r';

% Turn off axes ticks
h.ax.XTick = [];
h.ax.YTick = [];

setappdata(h.f, 'handles', h);
end

function updatebar(fig)
h = getappdata(fig, 'handles');
newxp = str2double(h.currentxpbox.String);
totalxp = str2double(h.totalxpbox.String);

h.expbar_L.YData = [newxp, 1];
h.expbar_R.YData = [totalxp - newxp, 1];
end
```

Gives us the following:

[image: yay]

You can manipulate the size and location of the `axes` object to suit your needs.